# How to auto search directories for `<img src=` [image] using javascript/php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I'm not sure but is possible to auto search directories for images src?
For example:
If my domain : `www.site.com`
Image source : `files/images/demo.jpg`
Simple way : `<img src="files/images/demo.jpg" />`

Is possible to do like this : `<img src="././demo.jpg" />`?

I'm trying but not working.

Comment: `src="././demo"` is identical to `src="demo"`. Add additional details to explain what/why you want to do that, in which application context, if php or javascript, server or client-side image searching, if a list exists, or you want to glob()-search for patterns etc.

Comment: I'm not professionalist in javascript and php but i'm using this in javascript and not working. @mario

Comment: Yes but not working @vinayakj

Comment: I'm getting not found in consle @vinayakj

Comment: It show me `http://localhost/demo.png` @vinayakj

Comment: I'm going to assume the image won't display because the image cannot be found. The image appears to be in > files > images folder. If you have the src target `src="demp.jpg"` you will be targeting the current directory "the same directory the page running is located" as for using `../` that will bring you back "out of a folder" If you want to make the directory look more clean you can set a sub-domain? images.mysite.com > mysite.com/files/images

Comment: I'm confused to what your question is. Are you asking if it's possible to search a directory for image files and return them or are you asking why your demo image isn't displaying when you type in an incorrect path...?

Comment: sorry but question is first part not 2nd part ok i removed @NewToJS

Comment: Yes, it is very possible. I have done something very similar. I used php, I will see if I can find the file as it will be a little much to start over again. I'm sure I could make a few changes to fit your question.

Comment: ok and if php then How? ........

Comment: @Dows I have submitted my answer, I hope this is the sort of thing you're looking for. If you need further assistance please leave a comment below my answer I will do the best I can.

Comment: ok wait testing........

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set the directory variable to the directory path you wish to scan.

I have added comments into the php so you can see step by step what is happening.

You can use ajax to call the php file to return all the names in that directory... It's up to you how you wish to impliment this into your existing source code. I have run this and checked it for any errors and all seems to be working fine.

```
<?php
$directory='images/';
//Scan the directory (returns array of files)
$files = scandir($directory);
//Remove "." and ".." from the files array 
unset($files[0],$files[1]);
//Create an array to hold the names.
$Images = array();
//Loop through each file found in the directory scan.
    foreach ($files as &$f) {
$docs=$directory.$f; 
//Get file information. (We want to check the extension)
$info=pathinfo($docs);
//Make the extension lowsercase before running the if condition.
$format=strtolower($info['extension']);
    //Check for allowed formats 
    if(($format=="jpg")||($format=="png")||($format=="gif")){
    //Places image name into the array if the format is a match
        $Images[]=$f;
    }
}
//Print the array of images. 
    print_r($Images);
?>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: I up-vote Thanks working but it is not what I 'm looking for @NewToJS

Comment: @Dows But this will search a directory for all images files as you told me you wanted. Can you edit your question and try be more clear with what you want to achieve? Once I have a better understand of what it is you are looking for, I will update my question if I have a solution for you. Also thank you for your up-vote.

Comment: No you answer is right but i simply want to know is that possible what i ask without creating array.

Comment: Ah I see. Well the array is needed as it holds multiple values/strings but you could have it select one random image from the array and return that. Not sure how or why you would scan for all images in a directory and return without the use of an array.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly the question, i think you can't auto search directories for images src because if you want to move up in levels you dont have to specify the directory (e.g, you're under `/files/images` you have just to use `../` to be under `/files`), contrary if you want to go down you have to specify the folder (e.g you're under `/files` and you want to be under `files/images/` you have to specify the `images` folder name because maybe there's many folders down in `files` directory) so there's no sign like `./` or something else can do that automatically.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks i understood your answer . @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: Is that what you looking for ?

Comment: Closely but i up-vote your answer